# "No source available" when debugging template methods in CDT

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I'm using GDB to debug a program in Eclipse CDT 8.1.1. It works fine, until I try to enter a template method. I then get a "no source available for ..." message and can no longer view the code, and I am forced to either go up the stack or switch to instruction stepping mode.

If I try to place a breakpoint inside the function itself, the program halts there, but it still loses sync with the source. In any case, the sync returns when I leave the template function.

How can I solve this, to enable me to properly debug template methods?